# Where is the mouse double click event for the DataGrid in Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-1.1

I don't see a mouse double click event for the DataGrid in Visual Studio 2003 in C# smart device application.

Does this event exist? And if so, how can I use it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to the **[`MouseDoubleClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx)**, the reason you aren't seeing it in Visual Studio 2003 is because it was added to the .NET Framework in version 2.0. VS 2003 uses version 1.1 of the .NET Framework.

When targeting this version of the .NET Framework, you'll need to use the [`DoubleClick` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick.aspx) instead. This event does not pass [`MouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx) like the `MouseDoubleClick` event, so if you need to know the current location of the pointer, you'll have use the [`Control.MousePosition` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[`DataGrid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagrid%28VS.71%29.aspx) inherits from [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28VS.71%29.aspx) and thus does it have a [`DoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doubleclick%28VS.71%29.aspx) event.